# How to modify JavaScript file on Drupal Site

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

Here is my problem:
I am in freelance and for a job on a Drupal site, I have to fix a JavaScript bug.

I find it, but I don't know how to "compile" my JavaScript file for the online site.
I mean that a find the right file, and modify the code and send it to the SFTP server but when I check the online site nothing change (even when a look at the file in the inspector, the program isn't modified.

I already try grunt command but nothing change.

Comment: Disable caching everywhere. If they use a service like Cloudflare, you will also need to have that cache disabled

Comment: Already try it on my side and the client did it too

Comment: What exactly did the client try? Disabling caching in the browser?

Comment: i don't know exactly, but they did something with the server. can it be anything else ?

Comment: If the file changes on the FTP (if someone can verify that), I don't see how it can be anything else

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is if your changes are reflected in your local development machine (view the file locally). For changes in Drupal JavaScript or css to be reflected, make sure you’re editing the right file (right subtheme).

1. Check exactly what file you edited by doing view source and seeing the path.
2. Clear cache at Drupal (if you are on Drupal 7 check performance->cache and google where exactly the path is on Drupal 8).
   CSS and js are aggregated and cached so cache clear re-creates them.
3. Clear the browser cache